# Spring security remember me not working, getting SecurityContex tHolder not populated with remember-me token

Tags: spring, spring-security, remember-me, autologin

i have below code to enable remember me authentication in configuration xml

```
<remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="testKeyForBlog" />

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="com.ringee.web.login.security.controller.CustomTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="key" value="testKeyForBlog"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="manageUserServiceImpl" ref="manageUserServiceImpl" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="tokenRepository" ref="managePersistentTokenServiceImpl" />
</beans:bean>
```

i have implemented AbstractRememberMeServices to have custom remember me authentication.

when i enter my login id and password with remember me check box enabled, RememberMeAuthenticationFilter filter is invoked, but below line

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null
```

where authentication object is not null, which eventually make remember me service not invoked, after running in debug mode , i see below debug message

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) SecurityContex
tHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'com.ringee.web.login.security.controller.CustomUserAuthentication@6ee367b0'
```

my application doesnt has form login, instead does ajax login, hence i have customized. i have custom entry point.

```
<http pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint">
        <custom-filter ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
        <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="testKeyForBlog" />
        <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ringeeFilter" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/menu/registration" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <custom-filter ref="logOutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

when login with remember me check box enable.. no cookie is been set because remember service is not getting invoked, since it authentication object has present already. dont know what is wrong with my configuration, thanks for you answers